# How will Chrome OS provide music?

Tags: google-chrome-os, spotify

I don't have many desktop apps installed; one of the few I have is Spotify.

How will Chrome OS provide music for its users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think they've announced any solid details so this is pure speculation, but if you listen to the [rumour mill](http://gigaom.com/2010/09/15/google-music-cloud-based-locker-streaming-and-downloads/) they'll have a cloud based 'hard drive' where you can store music purchased from Google themselves and listen back via a streaming service.

I think they'll offer quite a big cloud drive, which will probably be included in the price - like how Apple charge more for the 64GB iPad than the 32GB, Google may offer a staggered cloud drive correlating to a price. On this cloud drive I think it'll be possible to store photos, music, video etc.

I think it'll be very interesting to see what they offer and if it succeeds I believe it will be a game changer for a lot of IT products.

Answer (score 1):

I can see Spotify releasing a web based client. Spotify uses P2P to distribute data, and with methods for P2P transfer in the HTML5 spec it is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

http://music.google.com/about/

Comment: please expand your answer, link only answers are discouraged.